# Adding graphics to JPanel java

Tags: java, swing, graphics, jpanel, jcomponent

Making a small little game for my computer science class but im struggling to figure out how to add graphics to a JPanel here's what I have so far

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.*;


public class Map extends JComponent{
private JFrame frame;
private JPanel panel;

Map()
{
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500,500));
}

 @Override 
 public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
 super.paintComponent(g);          
 g.drawRect(100,150, 100, 100);
   }

public void makeMap()
{
    frame = new JFrame();
    panel = new JPanel();
    frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setTitle("MAP");
}
}
```

Comment: OK, you've given us broad requirements and some unexplained code (does it work? not work? how?), but you need to also ask a specific and answerable question. A little effort will go a long way towards getting good answers. Best I can do at present is give you this link for the Swing tutorials and other Swing resources: [Swing Info](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swing). If you give us more, then we can do likewise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not adding the `Map` component to the `JPanel` that you've created.
Basically you lack the following lines in `makeMap()`:

```
panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
panel.add(this);
```

Instead of setting the `BorderLayout` of the `panel` after its construction, you could also set it during construction, then it would look like this:

```
panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
panel.add(this);
```